# Get the coordinate of a certain position in OpenGL

Tags: java, opengl, graphics

How I get the values of x, y, and z in openGL, is there any get function to do that? 
I did a lot of glTranslatef commands, and now I want the x, y values of a certain coordinate in the window.

I have a project (maze game), and I want to prevent the main character from passing through the walls of the maze. The idea is to guide the character to a specific path by build a matrix of all valid positions in the maze.

I try to give the walls a physical property to have a rigid body, is there any known library in openGL help?

Comment: There is no built-in Opengl function for mouse that gets the 3D position in scene. You need to calculate it yourself (e.g ray casting). For the walls, if you want to give a rigid body that is "collusion detection". You can implement your own or use a physics engine.(example: "bullet physics")

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get those values form OpenGL as far as I know.
But you have two possibilities:

1. You can implement some raycasting to get the position
2. You can use the initial values (xyz) (I guess at some point in your porgram you will have access to them, and keep track of the position on your own. glTranslatef, glRotatef, glScalef are basically matrix multiplications. If you apply the same math to the vertex on the CPU as the GPU does, you should receive the same position in 3D. Depending on you model and what you want to archieve, this is very expensive...

For your problem you can use any physics engine in 3D or you can implement your own lib. For starters I would say you can create the Axis Aligned Bounding Box (AABB) or only the Oriented Bounding Box (OBB) and create the bounding Box of your character. Keeping track of the bounding box on the CPU using method 2, is not very expensive.
You just need to test for intersection of the BoundingBox of the player with the BoundingBox af EACH wall. The bottleneck here will be the amount of walls you have. The more walls he more time the testing will need, but you can speed this up using an octree and only test agains the walls which are in the same sub-space as your player.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box
http://www.euclideanspace.com/threed/animation/collisiondetect/